# "invent" and "orders"

Tags: meaning

> He also recognised that through the very process of perceiving and acquiring knowledge, we partly invent the world by our means of measuring it – in space and time and by the ‘orders’ he categorised as quantity, quality, reason and modality.

In the above sentence, does "invent" mean "create a secondary version"? And what does "orders" mean there – "concepts"?

Comment: "Partly invent" means "make a contribution to the reality of", "help create". This is intended in the philosophical, perception-is-reality sense (a la the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis). And "orders" simply means "categories", highly abstract organized collections of things which we use to give voice to the structure of the world (and, in so doing, elect that very structure itself).

Comment: @ Dan Bron  thank you for your explanation. And does "invent in the following sentence has the same meaning? 

"Hegel and his followers were to promote the notion that we invent the world we perceive"

Does it mean "...the notion that we contribute in the world we perceive" or "...the notion that we make the world we perceive"???

Comment: @DanBron Is it your usage of [a la](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_la#English) a broad usage?

Comment: @YohannV. Yes, but it is still recognized as a foreign term, so in formal contexts people will often still use the French diacritics, or even italics. But any generic native speaker would know what it meant.

Comment: @user127733 In both the original and your new quote, *invent* means "participate in the creation of".

Comment: @DanBron: Your comments are the best answer here. Please put them in an Answer.

Comment: The question should include a bit more context -- who is the author and what is the work, eg.

Answer (score 1):

In this context I would say that invent is the same as redefine. Orders would be the same as classifications. As you observe and analyze the world (or a part of it) you will abandon existing definitions and make your own definitions (or describe what you see in a new way) and classify things in new ways, by using different adjectives.

Answer (score 0):

Invent =to know our already known world in a new in a new perspective.

Orders = sequential arrangements/place in systematic method.

It is not a secondary version; it is a new version of one's own.

As everything is limited by time and space, he(the philosopher) categorises our perception as ...........